# Why SSRS reports (Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015) takes longer for particular users

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2015

We have some SSRS Reports in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015. 
When I run this report is taken 5 seconds and I get the result. When another crm user runs the same report for the same entity it is taking 40 seconds. Another user with the same security role is taking only 5 seconds (the only diference beetwen the users, the are in different business unit).

We cannot understand, why is for some users taking so long. But, it should be a reason, because it is always so.

I found, this link:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/why-do-ssrs-reports-run-longer-for-a-particular-user

It seems to be the same problem? But we don't understand, how to resolve it.

Has someone any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there infrastructure differences between you and the users? E.g. different networks?

Comment: No, everything is the same. If I loggin with this user from my computer, it is for me as well slow and from my computer with my user, it is fast. It is not logical..

Comment: Is the SSRS report itself running slowly or are the underlying queries running slowly? If this is on-premises you can profile the SQL server to catch query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM Reports use either FetchXML or the CRM Filtered Views.  Both of these take into account the security roles that a Microsoft CRM user is a member of.  If one user is a member of a role that has System Administrator level access and another user is a member or a role that has more limited User Level or Business Unit Level access, then the user with the System Administrator role will typically be able to run a CRM SSRS report faster than the user with the Business Unit level access.  This is because if the CRM User has Admin or Organizational access, the underlying SQL Queries that are generated by the CRM Platform can eliminate some of the WHERE Clause conditions that are needed to restrict the data returned for users with a security role that has more limited access.

I see in your question that your users have the same Microsoft Dynamics CRM Security role, but they are in different business units.  I would suspect that the amount of records is likely much greater in one of the business units than the other and is what's causing the difference in performance of this report.  If you capture a SQL Trace while running the report, you should be able to see the actual queries involved in the core part of the report and could run those in SQL Server Management Studio and then to show the query plans generated.  Note that if you have the Reads column included in the SQL Trace that you likely would see a significantly greater number of reads for the user with poor report performance.